# How do I make one line in this graph a different color from the rest?

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, seaborn

I have a graph, and I would like to make one of my lines different color

Tried using the matplotlib recommendation which just made me print two graphs

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sns

data = pd.read_csv("C:\\Users\\Nathan\\Downloads\\markouts_changed_maskedNEW.csv");
data.columns = ["Yeet","Yeet1","Yeet 2","Yeet 3","Yeet 4","Yeet 7","Exchange 5","Yeet Average","Intelligent Yeet"];
mpg = data[data.columns]
mpg.plot(color='green', linewidth=2.5)
```

Comment: drop `color='green'`, i.e, `mpg.plot(linewidth=2.5)`, pandas will automatically choose one color for each column.